# Sum levels wise binary tree

Tags: python, tree

I must implement a sum for each level in a binary tree
I must return a list that contains at position i, the ith sum
example: if I have this tree

```
      24
    /   \
   14    27
  / \  /  \
11  20 12  55
```

I must return [24, 41, 98]

I tried to implement this solution in python

```
def sommaperlivelli(p, lista):
if p == None:
    return 
if p.left != None and p.right != None:
    lista.append(p.left.key + p.right.key)
sommaperlivelli(p.left, lista)
sommaperlivelli(p.right, lista)
return lista
```

I can get only the first sum and I can't add the root. How I can do it?

this is the class that I use

```
class NodoABR:
def __init__(self, key = None, left = None, right = None, parent = None):
    self.key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.parent = parent
```

this is how I add node to the tree

```
def inserisciNodo(p, n):
if p == None:
    return NodoABR(n)
else:
    if p.key == n:
        return p
    elif p.key < n:
        rchild = inserisciNodo(p.right, n)
        p.right = rchild
        rchild.parent = p
    else:
       lchild = inserisciNodo(p.left, n)
       p.left = lchild
       lchild.parent = p 
return p
```

this is a BinarySearchTree
in main function I do this

```
p = NodoABR(24)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 14)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 27)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 11)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 20)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 12)
p = inserisciNodo(p, 55)
print(sommaperlivelli(p,[]))
```

Comment: You need to do a level-order traversal of the tree. In each level you would be able to sum up the values. Search online for "level order traversal"

Comment: You check if p does not equal None then add the root to the list. if p != None lista.append(p.key). Also it will be helpful if you can post the 'sommaperlivelli' function.

Comment: sommaperlivelli is this function, i call it for the left subtree and right subtree

Comment: You must do a Level Order traversal. Also Please post your complete code.

Comment: i must return [24, 41, 96] You expect the level of like root 24 , 1st level 41 and 2nd level  
98, respectively, I can't under you expect 96 how is come?  24,  14+27, 11+20+12+55

Comment: How your tree is set? Like this [24, [14, [11, 20], 27, [12, 55]]] for instance. We can't guess it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have similar Tree Node class, you can try this & modify to suite your particular needs.

```
from collections import deque

class Node:     # TreeNode eg.
    def  __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    
def LevelSum(root):
    answer = []
    
    if (root == None):  return 0        # base case

    result = root.data
    
    # track of # nodes at every level when traversal, and sum them up
    q = deque()
    q.append(root)
    
    while len(q):             #  > 0):
        size = len(q)

    # Iterate for all the nodes
        tot = 0   
         
        while size:      # meaning --- size > 0 
        # Dequeue an node from queue
            tmp = q.popleft()

        # Add this node's value to current sum.
            tot += tmp.data

        # Enqueue left and right children of dequeued node
            if (tmp.left != None):  q.append(tmp.left)
                
            if (tmp.right != None): q.append(tmp.right)
            
            size -= 1
        print(tot, result)

        answer.append(tot)
        
    return answer
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(1)
    root.left = Node(2)
    root.right = Node(3)
    root.left.left = Node(4)
    root.left.right = Node(5)
    root.right.right = Node(6)
    root.right.right.left = Node(9)
    root.right.right.right = Node(11)
    """
    # Constructed Binary tree is:
    #          1
    #        /  \
    #        2   3                 #  5
    #       / \   \
    #      4 5     6               # 15
    #             / \
    #             9   11           # 20
    """
    print("level sum is", LevelSum(root))
```

**[Edit]**  The PO author wants to learn another approach. (non-queue)

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import List


class Node:
    def  __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def level_sum(root: Node) -> int:
    
    def dfs(node, level):
        if not node: return
        
        total[level] += node.data
        dfs(node.left,level  + 1)
        dfs(node.right,level + 1)
        
    total = Counter()
    dfs(root, 1)

    print(total)     # showing each level & its total  --- can be commented out 
    
    return total.most_common()[0][1]    # the largest total
```

Comment: oh yeah thank you, but can I make a solution without a queue?

Comment: Sure. It's doable. But my post does answer your original PO. right?     (and deque is the built-in, wonder why cannot use it? And your PO did NOT has the constraint.)

Comment: Before I try another new answer, can you please list what's other **constraint** that you don't want to use?   And this could be accepted?

Comment: yes sure, your implementation is right and very useful to me. No constraint, just my curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Using your `NodoABR` class, here's a simple tree traversal, depth-first, where we note the level at each iteration, and use it to store the node values, `arr` is an array (or list) of lists, one for each level:

```
# Create sample tree
root = NodoABR(24, NodoABR(14, NodoABR(11), NodoABR(20)), NodoABR(27, NodoABR(12), NodoABR(55)))

def handle_node(nd, level):
    # Add a new level list if needed
    if len(arr) == level:
        arr.append([])
    # Append this node value to its proper level list
    arr[level].append(nd.key)

    # Recurse, increasing the level
    if nd.left is not None:
        handle_node(nd.left, level+1)
    if nd.right is not None:
        handle_node(nd.right, level+1)

# Main program
arr = []
handle_node(root, 0)
print(arr)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[24], [14, 27], [11, 20, 12, 55]]
```